# py2neo execute cypher to find path

Tags: path, cypher, py2neo

i use py2neo to find get path ,my function like this :

-----------------------my funciton   -----------------

```
def findrelationall1(graph_db,startmobile,endmobile):
    querystring='''MATCH(catelyn:Person {usernbr:%s}), (drogo:Person {usernbr:%s})
MATCH p=(catelyn)-[*..100]-(drogo)
RETURN p'''
    result=graph_db.run(querystring1)
    for x in result :
        dic1=dict(x)
        print dic1.values()
```

---

return is :

> [(c0d4730)-[:`a1_a2_201705` {count:4}]->(bf795f0)<-[:`b1_b2_201705`
>   {count:4}]-(ae68e9e)]

what  "(c0d4730) "  is ?  a node  ?
how can i use this value to return a node and property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the internal id. 
Try 
`from py2neo import remote remote(node)._id`
See [How to get automatic node ID from py2neo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44117334)