# How to get automatic node ID from py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I'm using py2neo 3.1.2 version with Neo4j 3.2.0 and I have a question about it. At Neo4J's web interface I can run the following query to get the nodes ids:

`MATCH (n:Person) RETURN ID(n)`

I'd like to know if there's something at py2neo API that does that same thing. I've already inspected the `Node` object, but I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update: Previous Answer does not work with new `py2neo` but this answer works

The current version of `py2neo` (4.0.0b12) dropped the `remote` method.  Now you can get the `NODE ID` by accessing the `py2neo.data.Node.identity` attribute.  It's quite simple.  Let's say I query my `neo4j` database using `py2neo` like this:

```
#########################
# Standard Library Imports
#########################

import getpass

#########################
# Third party imports
#########################

import py2neo

# connect to the graph
graph = py2neo.Graph(password=getpass.getpass())

# enter your cypher query to return your node
a = graph.evaluate("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n LIMIT 1")

# access the identity attribute of the b object to get NODE ID
node_id = a.identity
```

We can confirm the NODE ID by querying our database using the node id returned by the attribute.  If it worked correctly, `a` and `b` should be the same node. Let's do a test:

```
# run a query but use previous identity attribute
b = graph.evaluate("MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)={} RETURN n".format(node_id))

# test for equality; if we are right, this evaluates to True
print(a == b)
[Out]: True
```

Answer (score 4):

I've talked with [@technige](https://twitter.com/technige) at Twitter (py2neo's creator) and his answer was.

Ah right. It's a bit indirect but you can do:

`from py2neo import remote
remote(node)._id`